# CNAME and masking

Tags: iis, cname-record, iis-8.5

I need help with iis and CNAME

if i have a website on my iis, lets say: store.domain.com
and i want cname as follow: br.domain.com
i need the br.domain.com to stay as the url but to show the store.domain.com content of the website

what i want is similar to a status page from uptimeRobot (for ex.) where they give me the abilitry to type status.domain.com and i see a page from their server

please advice, thanks